Some error with the @Data and some getters/setters thing in Lombok
I don't know why, but my object class Product cannot create getters/setters with Lombok. Does this make sense? This is the Product object class.
package com.lab2.model;

import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    public String name;
    public double price;
}


Here is the problem, I tried to call the getters/setters methods, but Eclipse seems cannot get any getters/setters
I want to know about how Lombok create the getters/setters, and why this class cannot create the getters/setters class. I tried to check the dependencies, jar files, some Spring starters.

Probably need to enable annotation processors within Eclipse.  And here is a good place to start on annotation processing specific to lombok.

You would need to install Lombok plugin in your IDE. This link gives you the steps to install plugin for your IDE.
